# select data with np.where with multiple index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Update:
I tried the code by Valdi_Bo with some modification

```
df = df.dropna()
print(df.head(5))
a = df.to_numpy()
row, col = np.where(np.greater(a, 0.8) & np.less(a, 1.0))
selected_corr_df = pd.DataFrame([ (df.index[r][0], df.index[r][1], df.columns[c], df.iloc[r, c])
                                 for r, c in np.c_[row, col] ], columns = ['datetime','code', 'col', 'val'])
```

so that datetime is included
however, the result is

```
             datetime     code       col       val
0 2023-01-01 20:00:00  BTCUSDT   BTCUSDT  1.000000
1 2023-01-01 20:00:00  BTCUSDT   ETHUSDT  0.839907
2 2023-01-01 20:00:00  ETHUSDT   BTCUSDT  0.839907
3 2023-01-01 20:00:00  BNBUSDT   BNBUSDT  1.000000
4 2023-01-01 20:00:00  XRPUSDT  DOGEUSDT  0.804122
```

Don't know why 1.0 correlation is still included
I tried to print(row,col)

```
print(row,col)
[    0     0     1 ... 65307 65314 65317] [0 1 0 ... 7 4 7]
print(df.head(5).iloc[:,:5])
                              BTCUSDT   ETHUSDT   BNBUSDT   XRPUSDT   SOLUSDT
datetime            code                                                     
2023-01-01 20:00:00 BTCUSDT  1.000000  0.839907  0.628913  0.459101  0.685730
                    ETHUSDT  0.839907  1.000000  0.654618  0.401911  0.572358
                    BNBUSDT  0.628913  0.654618  1.000000  0.494672  0.561099
                    XRPUSDT  0.459101  0.401911  0.494672  1.000000  0.525257
                    SOLUSDT  0.685730  0.572358  0.561099  0.525257  1.000000
```

looks like some problem occour on the np.where function

I have the following dataframe, corr_df

```
                                BTCUSDT   ETHUSDT   BNBUSDT
datetime            code                                   
2023-09-30 22:00:00 BTCUSDT    1.000000  0.744847  0.758208
                    ETHUSDT    0.744847  1.000000  0.788360
                    BNBUSDT    0.758208  0.788360  1.000000
                    XRPUSDT    0.175308  0.165487  0.330017
                    SOLUSDT    0.392990  0.433611  0.573683
                    ADAUSDT    0.326387  0.465547  0.555164
                    DOGEUSDT   0.584677  0.572698  0.658798
                    TRXUSDT    0.396398  0.150638  0.330389
                    MATICUSDT  0.640225  0.603454  0.663140
                    DOTUSDT    0.741107  0.758502  0.844142
2023-09-30 23:00:00 BTCUSDT    1.000000  0.739415  0.775631
                    ETHUSDT    0.739415  1.000000  0.798653
                    BNBUSDT    0.775631  0.798653  1.000000
                    XRPUSDT    0.185117  0.172995  0.334012
                    SOLUSDT    0.407861  0.444603  0.579565
                    ADAUSDT    0.324440  0.462648  0.543445
                    DOGEUSDT   0.593054  0.577852  0.667520
                    TRXUSDT    0.414259  0.164620  0.344475
                    MATICUSDT  0.655499  0.613226  0.670288
                    DOTUSDT    0.744608  0.759279  0.846514
```

I want to get the pair names that meet the condition, with datetime as index

I tried to select the data with np.where
the condition is

```
np.where(corr_dict[corr_len]> 0.8) & (corr_dict[corr_len] != 1)
```

which output 2 arrays
I used 2 variable to store it

```
row, col = np.where(corr_dict[corr_len]> 0.8) & (corr_dict[corr_len] != 1)
```

However, I stuck when I tried to create a new df, named selected_corr_df
I tried to get the column name as 'pair1' column
and 2nd index name as 'pair2' column

```
selected_corr_df = pd.DataFrame(index=corr_dict[corr_len].index, columns=['pair1', 'pair2'])
```

But I only create errors

Comment: I believe you got your parentheses wrong: `np.where((corr_dict[corr_len]> 0.8) & (corr_dict[corr_len] != 1))` and you can use this to filter your df as such: `corr_dict[np.where((corr_dict[corr_len]> 0.8) & (corr_dict[corr_len] != 1))]`

Comment: What is `corr_len`? But indeed your parenthesis don't make sense `np.where(corr_dict[corr_len]> 0.8) & (corr_dict[corr_len] != 1)` is seen as `np.where(corr_dict[corr_len]> 0.8)` and `(corr_dict[corr_len] != 1)` separately, then combined with `&` which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: What is the relation between *corr_df* and *corr_dict*?
Please provide also the source data to create *corr_df*.

Comment: And what is your expected output for this source data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create your source DataFrame I used the following code:

```
txt = '''\
datetime            code       BTCUSDT   ETHUSDT   BNBUSDT
2023-09-30 22:00:00 BTCUSDT    1.000000  0.744847  0.758208
2023-09-30 22:00:00 ETHUSDT    0.744847  1.000000  0.788360
2023-09-30 22:00:00 BNBUSDT    0.758208  0.788360  1.000000
2023-09-30 22:00:00 XRPUSDT    0.175308  0.165487  0.330017
2023-09-30 22:00:00 SOLUSDT    0.392990  0.433611  0.573683
2023-09-30 22:00:00 ADAUSDT    0.326387  0.465547  0.555164
2023-09-30 22:00:00 DOGEUSDT   0.584677  0.572698  0.658798
2023-09-30 22:00:00 TRXUSDT    0.396398  0.150638  0.330389
2023-09-30 22:00:00 MATICUSDT  0.640225  0.603454  0.663140
2023-09-30 22:00:00 DOTUSDT    0.741107  0.758502  0.844142
2023-09-30 23:00:00 BTCUSDT    1.000000  0.739415  0.775631
2023-09-30 23:00:00 ETHUSDT    0.739415  1.000000  0.798653
2023-09-30 23:00:00 BNBUSDT    0.775631  0.798653  1.000000
2023-09-30 23:00:00 XRPUSDT    0.185117  0.172995  0.334012
2023-09-30 23:00:00 SOLUSDT    0.407861  0.444603  0.579565
2023-09-30 23:00:00 ADAUSDT    0.324440  0.462648  0.543445
2023-09-30 23:00:00 DOGEUSDT   0.593054  0.577852  0.667520
2023-09-30 23:00:00 TRXUSDT    0.414259  0.164620  0.344475
2023-09-30 23:00:00 MATICUSDT  0.655499  0.613226  0.670288
2023-09-30 23:00:00 DOTUSDT    0.744608  0.759279  0.846514
'''
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(txt), widths=[20, 11, 10, 10, 10])
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
df.set_index(['datetime', 'code'], inplace=True)
```

Then I created a *Numpy* array:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
```

To get row / column numbers of elements of interest, I ran:

```
row, col = np.where(np.greater(a, 0.8) & np.less(a, 1.0))
```

And finally, to get the result with **three** columns (*code*, *col* and *val*),
I ran:

```
selected_corr_df = pd.DataFrame([ (df.index[r][1], df.columns[c], df.iloc[r, c])
    for r, c in np.c_[row, col] ], columns = ['code', 'col', 'val'])
```

The result is:

```
      code      col       val
0  DOTUSDT  BNBUSDT  0.844142
1  DOTUSDT  BNBUSDT  0.846514
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well explained! I think I almost get the answer, but something wrong when I use the similar code.

Comment: I finally found out why the code doesn't work
```
print(df.iloc[0,0])
0.9999999999999997
```
so I just set the 1nd critera as np.less(a, 0.999)